# Which country is this license plate from?

Tags: driving, automobiles

I’m in Romania for few days and today I noticed this license plate. It was on a black G wagon and what surprised me the most is that it had a face with bandana on it. Any clues?

[image]

Comment: Definitely not compliant to any EU state because not displaying the country code

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is supposed to be a [French plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_France) from [Corsica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corsica) but it is definitely not compliant: French plates must be black on a white reflective background, with the sides blue, with on one side the EU flag (twelve yellow stars in a circle) with a white F identifying France, and only on the other side the region logo (here [the flag of Corsica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_and_coat_of_arms_of_Corsica)) and the number of the “département” (2B in this case, the code for [Haute Corse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haute-Corse), the northern part of the island).

The flag of Corsica is indeed “[a Moor's head in black wearing a white bandana above his eyes on a white background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_and_coat_of_arms_of_Corsica)”:

[image]

The plate should look like this to be valid:

[image]

There are a few exceptions for silver on black for old cars dating from back when plates were of that color, but this doesn’t apply here and the colors and materials don’t match.

It’s a very recent plate, the GE series was issued around February and March of this year (we just started the GF series).

Comment: In addition, that plate number doesn't seem to be recognized by the french plates database which you can use on various auto parts reseller.

Comment: What's the most likely explanation for how somebody got an invalid license plate? Is it a counterfeit?

Comment: Here it seems to be for looks, plus possibly some Corsican nationalism (as the car owner replaced the Euro band with another copy of the département band). The registration number itself might well be genuine in such cases, but the owner doesn’t like the way the official plate looks. In parts of the Eastern EU I have also heard of fake license plates being used to transfer used cars which were purchased abroad. While the driver is the legal owner (or driving the car on their behalf), but the car is not registered and not insured.

Comment: Driver thinks black plates look better on their black car and don’t give a f**k about whether they’re legal. They probably also think this reduces the chances of getting caught by speed traps and the like (you can’t bribe an automated system). Local police may not be aware they’re illegal plates (though they definitely should), and even if they say something you slip them a note and they forget having seen them? Something like that, probably.

Comment: Is it possible the plates could have been transferred by the owner of a classic car (with a black plate and white lettering) to a newer vehicle in some legal way ?

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine This is not even a legal classic license plate, this is a *fantasy* licence plate that can easily be ordered online. Black and White plates for classic cars are without the departement logo and the lettering is in relief ([img](https://fvstorageprod.blob.core.windows.net/img/762496/sans1_nd.jpg))

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine also in the current French system, you cannot transfer plates from one car to another, plates are assigned to a car once and never change after that. And as mentioned in the answer, that registration is (very) recent.

Comment: WIthout any reason to think it is a fake plate, I'd assume the driver just thinks it looks better on their car (this, plus the nationalism thing stated above). As long as the numbers are valid and readable, they should not fear to be fined. I had a "fake plate" done for my motorbike just because the new style plate would look ugly on it. Numbers are genuine, it just doesn't have the country/region on it.

Comment: @Jérôme Don't know what country you live in, but in France, having non conforming plates is definitely illegal and subject to fines. The colours of the plate and the reflectivity of the background (but not the letters) are mandatory. The mention of the country is mandatory. The only part for which there is a bit of flexibility is the section on the right side, where you can pick the region of your choice, not necessarily where you live or registered your car.

Comment: I do live in France. My plate was made on an old-style plate with the dashes done manually (I think they come with the raw plate on new style plates). I'm not saying it is perfectly legal, just saying who will bother as long as it is "functionnal"? I think the rule (as stupid as it is) states that there should be an existing "département" on the side and I often see people covering this with a fake one (traditional region like Pays Basque or fake one like Groland). They shouldn't be bothered, unless some police agent is seriously pissed off.

Comment: I heard about plates one could buy on the Internet that are meant to reflect the speed cameras light to make them unreadable when flashed. This, obviously, is a different case. That could be the reason for the plate in the OP, but without any hint I wouldn't suspect that right away.

Comment: @Jérôme There are two different allowed methods for making the plates, but only plates made by authorised professionals are allowed. They should bear the relevant agreement numbers. There are reasons for the rules, mostly for compatibility with ANPR systems. Any plate which is not made by a licensed professional following the rules is most definitely illegal and can result in a fine. A plate like in the question is very clearly illegal, there is absolutely no doubt about it. An invalid plate is also a reason for failing the "Contrôle Technique".

Comment: Probably this plate is for a show or meeting of some kind and not intended for public road usage.